# Mixed content на SO ru

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, https

Ну неприлично, в самом деле. Хорошо бы исправить.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgD4g.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: http://forum.guns.ru/forums/icons/forum_pictures/011046/thm/11046918.jpg