# Новый дизайн навигации по основным разделам сайта!

Tags: поддержка, дизайн, навигация

С радостью спешу сообщить, что в самое ближайшее время наш сайт получит обновленную версию навигации по основным разделам сайта! Коллеги, встречайте!

[image]

Изменения также коснутся Меты.

[image]

<sub>(Снимки сделаны на тестовой версии движка.)</sub>

Уверен, в будущем нас ждет еще больше приятных нововведений!

---

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что функционал сайта остается тот же, изменилось лишь представление. Если вы не можете найти какую–либо ссылку, пожалуйста, задайте вопрос в ответе к этому вопросу, я, в свою очередь, обновлю этот ответ пояснениями.

С нетерпением ждем ваших отзывов!

**Заметки**

1. Меню с сайтами, чатом и выходом (вверху слева надпись «Stack Exchange») перемещается в правую часть «шапки» и становится серой иконкой – логотипом Stack Exchange.
2. Иконка достижений преобразовалась из изображения графика, в изображения кубка. Также переехала вправо.
3. Очередь проверок из надписи преобразовалась в иконку с карандашом.
4. Раздел знаков «переехал» в выпадающие меню достижений (в меню сверху справа).

Comment: Грустно всё это. Так [ничего и не исправили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4806/181100).

Comment: @D-side а зачем эта кнопка? Ссылка есть в футере... :)

Comment: @intro94 затем, что хедер попадается на глаза раньше футера. Но здесь это оффтопик, если хотите обсудить выдвинутые предложения, предлагаю делать это в комментариях под тем ответом.

Comment: *задайте вопрос в ответе к этому вопросу* и вы получите ответ в форме комментария под вашим ответом, который является вопросом, который ... :-D

Comment: @D-side Опять же, кому–то нравится так, кому–то по–другому. Исправления будут для всех сайтов сразу, если будут. Чтобы исправлять, необходимо понять, что это действительно нужно. Для этого надо какое–то время с данным вариантом пожить.

Comment: @alexolut Ответ будет в обновлении вопроса в виде пояснений (а–ля новый пункт в заметках).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky enSO уже пожил с этим какое-то время. И там [народ указывает на те же проблемы](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343653/2076787), и соотношение голосов указывает на поддержку подавляющим большинством.

Comment: _в самое ближайшее время_ - это когда? сегодня? завтра? через неделю?

Comment: @D-side Верно! И проблемы решаются!

Comment: @Grundy Вероятно, как только проснется Лондон и обновит сборку, если никто не заболеет или чего другого не случится.

Comment: _(Снимки сделаны на тестовой версии движка.)_ - можно ли как-то включить эту тестовую версию? Вроде как галочка была для английской версии, есть ли что-то подобное для нас?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Неужели так плохо?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ладно, я немного остыл и попробую сказать более внятно.

Comment: Из объективного: 1) Мне категорически не нравится, что спрятали ссылку на справку. 2) Поиск и Задать вопрос стали дальше друг от друга.

Comment: @NickVolynkin справка нужна только нубам, которым, сюприз, кнопка справки и показывается вместо очереди проверок (напоминаю, нужна репутация 500).

Comment: @Alex78191 хм, действительно. Ладно, это уже что-то.

Comment: Не похоже, что сейчас полночь...

Comment: Раньше было лучше.

Comment: Давно тыкал ещё на английском SO, старый нравился сильно больше. Также не могу понять почему, но в новом дизайне число непрочитанных уведомлений для меня совершенно незаметно, теряется на белом фоне что ли

Comment: @andreymal, контраст мал, согласен.

Comment: @andreymal самое заплюсованное предложение и временное решение это [сделать верхнюю панель тёмной](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343685/2076787).

Comment: Наконец-то! Дождался)

Comment: На скриншоте Меты откуда-то конкурсные вопросы появились..

Comment: Старый фон был лучше. Из-за нового фона глаза болят.

Comment: Все это здорово, но иметь mixed content на сайте программистов и, как следствие, отсутствие зеленого замочка в Chrome - ну позорище же чистой воды. Я уже обращал на это внимание на Мете. Неужели трудно всего одну картинку (http://i.stack.imgur.com/DXb3V.png) дать по https?

Comment: @KAGGDesign я толкнул [ваш вопрос по этой теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5250/mixed-content-%D0%BD%D0%B0-so-ru) повыше, в текущие вопросы Меты. Но к этому "вопросу" (?) он не имеет приблизительно никакого отношения.

Comment: @D-side спасибо, что толкнули выше.

Comment: А что с мобильной версией?

Answer (score 12):

## [НУ И ПЛОХО ЭТО!](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/105047/97304)

> [image: SO header]

С первого взгляда видно типичную современную ориентированность на touch-интерфейсы.
Но временно забудем об этом и посмотрим на функциональность.

## [Справка](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343165/4928642) нам больше не нужна!

> [image: Справка перемещена]

На самом деле, через <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> можно найти её в футере:

> [image: в футер]

Хотя нет, она ещё есть в выпадающем меню:

> [image: Скриншот с меню]

и показывается для пользователей с низкой репутацией

> [image: Скриншот от @MikhailSibirev]

## Знаки?

> [image: Нет знаков]

**Нашлись:** они в достижениях

> [image: знаки в достижениях]

## [Похожие иконки должны идти подряд?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343988/4928642) Нет!

> [image: Navigation]

<s>3 иконки из 4 открывают выпадающий список, но одна в середине - ведёт на другую страницу.</s> **ИСПРАВЛЕНО:** 4 выпадающих списка.

И все они срабатывают только по клику.

К тому же, эта иконка даже семантически не относится к тому же блоку. Это [очередь проверок](/review), которая ведёт на обычную страницу сайта, которая не относится к конкретному пользователю.

## [Как перейти на другой сайт?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343986/4928642)

> [image: старый список сайтов]

Да, Я гораздо больше хожу между сайтами, чем смотрю пользователей и теги.
Но теперь это всего лишь мелкая кнопка на другом конце списка.

> [image: new sites list]

#### Есть куча случаев, когда она нужна:

- Я на мете и хочу перейти на основной сайт
- Я пришёл отвечать, а не спрашивать, и ищу интересные вопросы (на разных сайтах)
- Я хочу спросить на другом языке
  [Why are some question-askers active on both English and Russian Stack Overflows?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/276523/309650)
- Я понял, что другой сайт лучше подходит для вопроса (например, Superuser vs SO)
- Я перешёл на сайт через ссылку ассоциации и хочу вернуться обратно
- Я обнаружил что-то на основном сайте и хочу обсудить на мете
- И ещё куча всего

## [Поиск?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343992/4928642) Отцентрировать!

> [image: старый поиск]
>
> [image: search]

Не уверен, что это плохо, но это довольно непривычно, поскольку у большинства сайтов он в правом верхнем углу.

---

---

---

## Возможно я неправ, или что-то упускаю, но мне этот дизайн не нравится.

Comment: Можно завернуть скриншоты, скажем, в цитаты. Чтобы можно было визуально отделить их от окружающего текста.

Comment: *3 иконки из 4 открывают выпадающий список, но одна в середине - ведёт на другую страницу. И все они срабатывают только по клику.* -- уже неактуально.

Comment: @D-side, ну хоть что-то хорошее.

Comment: Следующий шаг — адаптация сайта для консолей и VR. Будем вообще с джойстиком на сайт ходить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin недовольные модераторы будут расстреляны!

Comment: Вы просто привыкли к этому интерфейсу, а как известно к чему-то новому привыкнуть сложно.

Comment: Зато удобно, что дизайн не меняется при переходе с английской версии. Справка [есть в списке](https://i.imgur.com/44Y7yiZ.png) сообществ, алло.

Comment: Знаки – бессмысленная ерунда как на Xbox и PS. Ссылка на них есть по кнопке достижения.

Comment: Не нужно распыляться по всем сообществам, времени на все не хватит.

Comment: @Alex78191 я бы вообще оставил для новичков: половина страницы — поле с поиском, вторая половина — большая кнопка справки. А «Задать вопрос» — спрятать, как справку сейчас.

Comment: @NickVolynkin как тогда репутацию зарабатывать?

Comment: @Alex78191 я предполагаю, что в основном люди сюда ходят за решениями и знаниями, а не за репутацией. Есть частая проблема: люди не ищут по сайту, а сразу задают свой вопрос.

Comment: Справка нужна только новичкам, которым, сюприз, кнопка справки и показывается вместо очереди проверок (напоминаю, нужна репутация 500).

Comment: @NickVolynkin кстати при задании вопроса автоматически поиск показывается, удобно.

Comment: У меня есть кнопка справки. Что я сделал не так? http://screenshot.ru/upload/image/zjVk

Comment: @MikhailSibirev, не успел набрать достаточно репутации. Вроде по одной из ссылок было написано, что кнопки разные в зависимости от репутации. А вообще, я справку уже в другом месте нашёл.

Comment: @MikhailSibirev https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5312/%d0%9d%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0#comment19821_5313

Comment: Так, осталось дождаться сайта-обёртки (со старым дизайном) поверх SE API. Либо запросить у разработчиков поддержку *расширенных* тем оформления (чтоб не только графические мелочи, но и навигацию можно было бы задавать). Хотя я знаю, что мне ответят на это на метамете.

Comment: @Alex78191 Как мне кажется, внешний вид не менее важен, чем функционал. Весь движок Stack Overflow, по большому счету, построен на отзывах/идеях сообщества. Я не нахожу уместными какие–либо шутки или троллинг в вопросе, где обсуждается будущее сайта. Пожалуйста, придерживайтесь конструктивных аргументированных предложений по теме вопроса.

Comment: Знаки, кстати, в достижениях есть. Там, где точка с UTC.

Comment: Я аж всплакнул от этого ответа. Ты показал все недостатки этого дизайна :) Иди в модераторы и админы

Comment: @Yuri вы легко внушаемы.

Comment: @Alex78191, на костёр Вас! Всех несогласных сжечь :D

Comment: Справку вернули! Ура-а-а!

Comment: @D-side, она там с конца winter bash'а.

Answer (score 5):

Ура! Ну наконец-то новый дизайн добрался и до ruSO!

Из плюсов стоит отметить

- Плавающую шапку, которая теперь всегда вверху страницы, что позволяет быстрее замечать новые уведомления на сайте. Кроме того, появился более быстрый доступ к проверкам — теперь нет необходимости загружать страницу со списком очередей.
- Эта плавающая панель навигации отключаема в настройках (пункт пока не переведён).
- Более широкое поле поиска по сайту, что упрощает ввод поискового запроса.

Но в целом, изменения в расположении элементов не столь существенны, чтобы кричать "всё пропало!" Команда дизайнеров Stack Overflow потрудилась на славу. И если сравнивать с другими недавними изменениями дизайнов популярных сайтов, то SO однозначно на высоте!

Comment: Ты на мете часто бываешь? Переход между метой и сайтом справа в углу не бесит?

Comment: На мету обычно перехожу из блока обсуждаемых вопросов или изредка из чата...

Comment: А вот я через меню. И по сайтам ru/en/codegolf довольно часто...

Comment: @Qwertiy а идти в угол за ответами не бесит? Можно их порядок [сменить](https://i.imgur.com/0qZyL5K.png)

Comment: @Qwertiy Хотите чтобы [так](https://i.imgur.com/WLoa5Rd.png) было? Или можно [так](https://i.imgur.com/FJoVXZC.png). Можете задать вопрос на ruSO, вам помогут с реализацией данного изменения.

Answer (score 5):

Меня, в принципе, устраивает где располагаются кнопочки и как добраться до различных мне нужных пунктов. Вечно мозолившая глаза цифра очереди проверок теперь внутри значка-открывашки сверху-справа. Это радость)

Ничего критичного, из-за чего можно на месяц уйти в запой и депрессию — я не заметил.

Что мне точно не понравилось:

1. То, что при по иконкам сверху-справа нужно обязательно кликать, чтобы раскрыть окошко. Хотелось бы, чтоб окошки открывались либо сразу по наведению, либо если кликнул на одну иконку и открылось окошко, то на другие достаточно уже было бы просто навести мышку.
2. Дело вкусовщины, но всё же — это рыжий вырвиглазный стиль оформления. Это явно стиль 5-ти летней девочки из Архангельска, которая исписала всю акварельку и у неё остался только этот цвет СССР-овских штор и обоев.

   Однако для себя лично эту проблему я решил поставив расширение для браузера *Stylish* и скомбинировав пару настроек..Кто не доволен дизайном шапки - можете поступить как я и написать свои или взять [что-то из готовых пользовательских](https://userstyles.org/styles/browse?category=stackoverflow).

   Мои стили, если (а вдруг) кому нужно — представлены ниже (при появлении в очереди проверок новых поступлений - значок рыжим подсвечиваться не будет!!!):

```css
.top-bar {
    border-top: 0 !important;
    background: rgba(12,13,14,0.86);
    height: 42px;
}

.top-bar~.container {
    padding-top: 42px !important;
}

.top-bar .-logo,
.top-bar .navigation .-list,
.top-bar .secondary-nav .-list{
    height: 42px !important;
}


.top-bar .secondary-nav .-link {    
    color: #dedede;
}

.top-bar .-logo:hover {
 background-color: #eff0f1;
}

/* Always use the small glyph instead of full logo */
.top-bar .-logo {
 width: 25px;
}

.top-bar .-logo .-img {
 height: 30px;
 width: 25px;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
}

.top-bar .navigation .-item._current .-link{
    color: #fff;    
}


.top-bar .navigation .-item._current .-link:focus {
 color: #242729;
}

.top-bar .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input,
.top-bar .searchbar .btn {
 height: 32px;
}

.top-bar .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input {
 color: #c5c9ce;
 background: #464748;
 border-color: #6a737c;
 box-shadow: none!important;
}

.top-bar .searchbar .btn [role="icon"] {
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
}

.top-bar .-ctas .btn-clear {
 color: #0095ff;
}

.top-bar .-ctas .btn-clear:hover, 
.top-bar .-ctas .btn-clear:focus {
 color: #0086e6;
 background-color: rgba(148, 155, 160, 0.3);
}

.top-bar .navigation .beta-badge {
    top: 26px !important;
}

.top-bar .my-profile {
    padding: 9px 10px !important;
 color: #848d95;
}

.top-barr .my-profile { 
 height: 35px;
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

.top-bar .my-profile .-rep {    
    color: #dedede;
}


.top-bar .my-profile:hover .-rep.js-header-rep,
.top-bar .my-profile:hover .-badges .badgecount {
    color: #2d2e2f;
}

.top-bar {
    border-top: none;
 background: #2d2e2f;
    height: 34px;
}

.top-bar .-logo._glyph {
    width: 66px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    height: 36px !important;
}

.top-bar .-logo .-img._glyph {
    height: 38px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.top-bar .-logo._glyph:hover {
    background: #eff0f1;
}

.top-bar .-logo._glyph .-img {
 width: 28px;
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.top-bar .-logo .-img {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    background-position: 0px 4px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQEQt.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.top-bar .navigation .-item._current .-link {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #a9a9a9;
    color: #dedede;
}

.top-bar .navigation .-item._current .-link:hover {
    color: #2d2e2f;
}


.top-bar .navigation .-link {
 height: 34px !important;    
}



.top-bar .secondary-nav .-link { 
    height: 35px !important;
}

.gravatar-wrapper-24 {
 width: 37px;
}

.gravatar-wrapper-24 img { 
 height: 34px;
    width: 36px;
}

.top-bar .secondary-nav .-link._highlighted-reviews, .top-bar .secondary-nav .-link._highlighted-reviews:hover, .top-bar .secondary-nav .-link._highlighted-reviews.topbar-icon-on {
    color: #dedede;
}

.top-bar .secondary-nav .-item._active, .top-bar .secondary-nav .-item .-link.topbar-icon-on, .top-bar .secondary-nav .-item .-link._highlighted-reviews:hover { 
    color:black;
}

.top-bar .navigation .-link {    
    color: #dedede;
}

.top-bar .secondary-nav .-link._danger-indicator:after { 
     right: 9999px;
}
```

---

Выглядит это так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем черный header на светлом сайте?

Comment: Он такой был с самого начала, как и у большинства ресурсов сети SE: https://academia.stackexchange.com/ , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ и пр. Вполне себе существуют. Как и существуют нормально другие сайты в интернете с подобными шапками. Можно подумать они должны быть светлые на светлом и темные на темном. Странная логика.

Answer (score 4):

Верните всё, как было. По крайней мере большниство. Хотя бы как опцию. Стало только хуже и неудобней. Не уверен, что у меня получится очень красноречиво было объяснять, чем именно этот новый интерфейс плох.

Нельзя сказать, что он худшее в мире зло. Просто на фоне предыдущего он выглядит серьёзным откатом/деградацией/шагом назад (выберите нужное).

И не надо только говорить, что это просто потому, что я не привык. И вешать ярлыки консерваторов/противников прогресса на тех, кто просто считает что стало хуже. К чему-то хорошему быстро привыкаешь.

Comment: @Alex78191 Да что тут принимать. Всё равно что владельцы вк, что владельцы stackoverflow с вероятностью 99,9999% не заинтересуются мнением кто не считает что новые дизайны были удачны (даже если их будет много), поэтому можете ничего не доказывать, просто минусануть и проходить мимо.

Comment: Если разрабы не возьмутся, можно самим у себя править шапку на старую. Стили/разметку выпросить можно или вытянуть из машин времени :)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Не знаю как в VK, но руководству Stack Overflow крайне важно мнение участников. Конечно же, мнения могут расходиться, так случается, ничего плохого в этом нет. Нам крайне важна количественная оценка. К пример, вы можете сказать, что то и это испортилось, оценить можно так–то. Мы это проверим, и, если это правда, исправим. Новым дизайном, мы, конечно, хотим улучшись систему, а не ухудшить. В старом дизайне было много недочетов, которые мы хотим исправить в новом. Например, кнопка задать вопрос не должна выглядеть также, как и раздел сайта. И таких недочетов было много.

Comment: дуров верни стену!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А сколько надо голосов "за" или что можно попробовать сделать (на основании общественного мнения, разумеется), чтобы вернули старый дизайн? И чтобы все инновации исходили  из старого дизайна и какой-то внятной целесообразности.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я не хочу на главном сайте тянуть мышку вправо, а на этом влево.

Answer (score 0):

Самое плохое в новом дизайне то, что на разных сайтах он разный. Т.е. перемещаясь между сайтами сети менюшки оказываются то справа, то слева, и ты каждый раз путаешься заходя на другой сайт.

Если бы, допустим, этот дизайн применили-бы сразу для всех сайтов сети, к нему можно было бы привыкнуть за несколько дней, и не обращать в дальнейшем на это никакого внимания. Но нет, SO пошел по другому пути, и теперь переходя между сайтами надо заново запускать процесс «адаптации», грубо говоря, растянув в целом этот процесс на долгие годы, пока все сайты не перейдут на новый дизайн

Comment: На самом популярном сайте enSO он давно.

Comment: Именно поэтому в последнее время туда не заходил

Comment: Не программируете?

Comment: @Alex78191 из за дизайна

Comment: • https://i.imgur.com/h6Ihmw5.png • https://i.imgur.com/LKUMOoq.png