# Чёрная полоса под полосой навигации

Tags: дефект, дизайн

С сегодняшнего для появилась полоса , прилагаю скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой браузер и условия этого бага? А то я такого не наблюдаю.

Comment: у меня с кастомным стилем всегда такая (почти такая))) https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5381/191482  ........ а вообще такой полосы не наблюдаю у себя  в браузерах

Comment: Chrome, FF: не воспроизводится на последних версиях.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov это в Chrome только

Comment: @МаксимЛенский У меня такого не наблюдается.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ну видите же скрин ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский А если проблема у других людей не вопроизводится, как это решать?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov х.з .. вопрос можно `закрыть` но он не решён

Comment: @МаксимЛенский А ОС у вас какая?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Винда 7

Comment: Google Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) под Windows 10  - полёт нормальный. Никаких полос.

Comment: @МихаилРебров вот видео , смотрите : https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LJLp/yKVnTvZhH

Comment: Да мы Вам верим @МаксимЛенский ,

Comment: @МихаилРебров кто такой умный минус мне влепил ??как будто я выдумал что то

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , попробуйте многочисленные плагины и приложения Хром отключить....как-то их много и чую я в ком-то может быть причина

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , минусы на SO - обычное дело(не всегда они оправданы). не стоит по этому поводу переживать до тех пор пока Ваш вопрос не удалили.

Comment: @МихаилРебров я выключил все плагины расширения но проблему это не решило

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , а как тени под другими объектами в браузере отображаются? попробуйте скопировать box-shadow c хедера в инспекторе и прикрутить их куда нибудь ещё?...может банальное Ctrl+F5 поможет?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60265/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: @МаксимЛенский А в других браузерах той же ОС та же проблема?

Answer (score 2):

1. Убедитесь, что вы не используете кривой User CSS. Отключите расширения, откройте в другом браузере.
2. Убедитесь, что ваша видеокарта всё ещё работает. На месте чёрной полосы должна быть полупрозрачная тень.

Comment: я вообще не использую всякие сторонние css только те что есть в броузере , и этот косяк только в Chrome

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Тени на других сайтах рисуются правильно? Попробуйте отключить аппаратное ускорение видео в настройках хрома.