# Интерфейс сайта

Tags: поддержка, дизайн

Хотелось бы поделиться впечатлениями от пользования сайтом stackoverflow, в частности от пользования его интерфейсом.

Интерфейс сайта крайне неудобен и запутан: например, я никак не могу найти кнопку или ссылку выхода из аккаунта\сайта. Возможно таковые просто не предусмотрены, но нигде об этом не сказано почему-то или до такой информации трудно добраться.

В правом верхнем углу, для меня, не посвященного и скорее всего для новичка, расположены кнопки непонятного назначения, где при открытии, например первой слева, открывается страница где много разных разделов, которые "сливаются" и визуально плохо разграничены. Код в сообщение можно вставить тремя разными способами: апострофами, alt+K (если не ошибаюсь), и еще перед каждой строкой исходного кода должен быть отступ 4 пробела... Зачем так много и сложно? Справка **оформлена** из рук вон плохо.

И что это значит и почему **именно** пробелом не работает? - *"для переноса строки завершите предыдущую 2 пробелами"*

---

Здесь я озвучил лишь небольшую толику своих ощущений и это сугубо мое личное мнение, возможно отличное от мнения остальных участников. Но еще раз повторюсь - данный ресурс в первую очередь предназначен для быстрого поиска ответов на животрепещущие вопросы и получается так, что быстрое получение ответа медленно и планомерно перетекает в изучение интерфейса.
На мой скромный взгляд все должно быть проще, визуально разграниченно и унифицированно и привычней большинству посетителей.

---

Скрины
[image: оформление справки]

[image: оформление страницы]

[image: оформление страницы2]

[image: почему так?]

---

Так понятней выглядет
[image: интерфейс справки]

Comment: "я никак не могу найти кнопку или ссылку выхода из аккаунта\сайта" в правом верхнем углу кнопка выводит всплывающее окно, в нем есть выход

Comment: _> Справка оформлена из рук вон плохо_ - конструктивная критика будет?

Comment: "Код в сообщение можно вставить тремя разными способами" - еще четвертый: руками теги <pre><code> добавить

Comment: *"не могу найти кнопку или ссылку выхода из аккаунта\сайта"* -- информативно (можно ответить: если бы эту операцию многим людям часто приходилось делать, то можно было бы её более заметной сделать, иначе достаточно вопрос на Мета спросить/найти: "как выйти из сайта" если не можете выйти самостоятельно) *"справка оформлена из рук вон плохо"* -- не информативно: какие конкретные проблемы текущее оформление справки вызывает по вашему мнению и как их можно исправить (картинка тысячи слов стоит)

Comment: @alexolut, не является дубликатом, так как более обширный.

Comment: 1. Да, конечно будет и конструктивная критика (заметьте - Оформления) справки, вот только не нашел как прикрепить скрин. 2. Я знаю что такое markdown и, почему-то считаю излишним предлагать несколько способов форматирования одного и того же, (можно объеденить способы, например на выбор пользователя). 3. Выход нашел, кстати, почему многие думают, что им мало кто пользуется? Даже моя мама использует выход из аккаунта, не здесь конечно, но тем не менее. 4. Кнопочки не раздражают, просто необходимо определенное время, чтобы понять их назначение 5. 47 символов осталось - остальное в сл. посте

Comment: @Arhad значит, надо закрыть как "слишком общий"

Comment: 5. Оформление страницы практически не разграничено https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/207485/andry 6. Именно пробелом не работает (написано в справке) - "для переноса строки завершите предыдущую 2 пробелами". Работает Enter'om, но тут возможно проблема в переводе. 7. Изучать все премудрости обычному пользователю вряд ли захочется, ему нужно "чтоб быстро", ведь ресурс предназначен для широкого круга посетителей.

Comment: 8. Я рад, что и у нас в стране появляются такие хорошие ресурсы как stackexchange, stackoverflow, тостер, где можно задать вопрос и в короткое время получить ответ. Но честно сказать, stackoverflow тяжеловат в освоении. 9. Я озвучил сугубо свое личное мнение и моей целью не было затронуть чьих-либо чувств и если это случилось, то прошу меня извинить.

Comment: Часть проблем, которые вы озвучили, появились в новом дизайне, который [встретили очень неоднозначно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5312/181100). Но на обратную связь в Stack Overflow (компании) отреагировали очень слабо.

Comment: Спасибо. А я то думал, что я один такой :)

Comment: @andry Переходи на [тёмную сторону](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5381/191482) :) Дизайн, конечно, тот еще. Но разрабы на столько ленивы, что проще сварганить свои стили :-/

Comment: @andry на самом деле то, что вы сейчас добавили в скринах - это банальное неознакомление со справкой и первоначальным экскурсом по ruSO, которое **всегда** показывается при регистрации на сайте новому участнику. Т.е. интерфейс может быть не идеален, но проблема, что вы в этих штуках путаетесь - вина полностью ваша)

Comment: Чтобы просто задать вопрос даже регистрация не нужна. Есть кнопка ["Задать вопрос"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmsq9.jpg).

Comment: @andry я не понял что это за цифры ты ставишь и что  `3.?` - значит. Но как написал @alexolut - задать вопрос можно вообще не регистрируясь и просто жмакнуть кнопку которая мутированая и видна даже слепым

Comment: *"оформление храмает"* — не информативно (как было бы лучше? какую задачу текущее оформление мешает выполнить?)¶  Основная претензия я так понял, что интерфейс сложный: много в нём всякого поэтому можно запутаться. Ответ простой: чтобы задать, ответить на вопрос вам не нужно знать что все эти кнопочки и ссылки означают. Со временем, по мере необходимости освоите¶ Если какую-то конкретную задачу вы считаете можно было бы проще выполнить, чем текущий интерфейс, то спрашивайте¶ В сторону: 1- сайт американский. My traceroute говорит, что сервер в Калифорнии 2- два пробела предохраняют новую строку

Comment: Прошу прощения, запамятовал. Запарился, проще говоря). Про цифру: 3.? = (...и на хрена мне это?) можно не обращать внимания. Сообщение удалю, дабы никого не вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: @ jfs у меня нет претензий. Интерфейс таки сложный. 2- два пробела предохраняют новую строку. Об этом не знал. Спасибо.

Comment: @alexolut, мне кажется, фразы "разблокировать тревоги / голосование" не очень красиво там выглядят. Есть ли какой способ улучшить их формулировку?

Comment: @andry: "претензия" это я неудачно слово выбрал. Я хотел выразить мысль, что есть разница между complex и complicated. Ещё раз: если есть конкретная задача, которую по вашему мнению можно было проще бы выполнить или конкретное предложение как улучшить пускай самый маленький аспект сайта, то спрашивайте. Не смотря на то что тут некоторые господа заявляют, сайт постоянно изменяется, в том числе с учётом предложений от простых участников как мы с вами. Вот конкретный пример (чтобы вы представление имели) [моего предложения об изменении интерфейса (в ios приложении)](https://goo.gl/7BgYcD)

Comment: Ничего страшного в претензии нет :) Просто я так, на всякий случай озвучил что я "без претензий". Люди все разные и по-разному могут отреагировать. А что до интерфейса и сложностей, так это моя перфекционисткая привычка, которой я и сам бываю не рад. А тут как раз проблема нарисовалась, которую я не решил из-за неграмотности в php, вот и прошелся я по интерфейсу до кучи :)

Answer (score 9):

Кнопка выхода находится в меню в правом верхнем углу среди тех кнопочек, которые вы так обругали.

[image: кнопка выхода]

Для форматирования сообщений на сайте используется [Markdown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) - простой язык разметки текста, надмножество HTML. По сути это уже стандарт индустрии, исходный код на Markdown легко читать, и результат не дурный. С примерами можно ознакомиться в [справке по редактированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Кнопочки над полем ввода вопросов или ответов предназначены для упрощения набора кода сообщений. Можете ими не пользоваться, если раздражает.