# У меня слетел шрифт или это очередное обновление?

Tags: обсуждение, обновление

У меня вдруг буквы стали меньше (хоть и более скругленые), читать стало хуже. Это обновление для всех или просто у меня что-то произошло?

Comment: Для всех, привыкайте

Comment: Это называется «системные шрифты» https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021

Comment: Не удивительно, что в похожие для этого топика попала тема  “Закат Stack Overflow”.

Comment: А как-то назад вернуть можно?

Comment: Нда... Английский ubuntu хорош, но русский -- угловато будет

Comment: То "болото", то изменения не нравятся .. чудные мы ) Нормальный шрифт кстати.

Comment: @avp Если поставить на убунту шрифты с винды, то они будут использоваться вместо "ubuntu". Вот тут инструкцию делал: https://askubuntu.com/a/1312102/618002

Comment: Ужасный шрифт. Предыдущий был гораздо лучше.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо. Попробовал, сделал как у вас написано, все скачал, установил в ~/.local/share/, перегрузил. Никаких изменений в шрифтах тут (ruSO) не вижу. А вот в вике вроде поменялось...  Может проблема в том, что у меня не совсем убунта, а Mint с циннамоном?

Comment: @avp Хмм. У меня в тексте "Segoe UI", а в коде все равно "Ubuntu mono". Вот еще какой-то [скрипт для возврата шрифтов](https://stackapps.com/q/8932/79227) откопал, пытаюсь запустить...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, этот скипт на JS (если не ошибаюсь) надо как-то в Firefox-е запускать? (если честно, это для меня темный лес)

Comment: @avp Поставил на FF расширение GreaseMonkey. При клике на "Custom Fonts 1.2.1, with original fonts" он сам предложил установить скрипт.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, что-то надоело мне с этим возиться... Подождем, может админы сайта сами сообразят, что лучше им самим все исправить

Comment: @avp Что-то я сомневаюсь. :) Ниже ответ запостил, со всеми ссылками.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, увидел. Попробовал. Сейчас перезапущу FF и сообщу

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вроде сработало, на первый взгляд как и раньше выглядит, может немного размыто, но это трудно верифицировать -)

Comment: Наконец-то родной San Francisco...

Comment: Это обновление наверняка будет еще не раз обновлено. На [английской мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/756067) неплохой такой бунт, плюс багов в верстке из-за смены шрифта понавылезало.

Comment: Я, как очкарик давно на всех страницах нажимаю Ctrl **+** до 150%. И не парюсь.

Comment: Шрифт опять поменяли :( С одной стороны, он стал более программерского начертания, чем клоунского, с другой - очень бледный, как будто в настройках шрифта неправильную плотность или чего-то там выбрали.

Comment: @MBo мне он кажется слегка размытым, будто линии толщиной в дробное количество пикселей. Снова активировал скрипт и сразу стало хорошо :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, именно так. Надеялся, что без скрипта переживу эти эксперименты, но, видимо, Остапов несёт, пришлось тоже поставить.

Answer (score 6):

Нашел [скрипт](https://stackapps.com/q/8932/79227), который возвращает старые шрифты.

На Firefox устанавливается так:

1. Сначала ставим расширение [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).
2. Потом жмякаем [сюда](https://stackapps.com/q/8932/79227), внизу нажимаем `Custom Fonts <version>, with original fonts` - должно вылезти предложение установить скрипт. Соглашаемся.

Comment: во, можно хоть читать теперь, а то сегодня за первые десять минут аж глаза устали

Comment: Для хрома [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=ru)

Comment: Ещё один метод для Firefox (используя Stylus): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364269/

Comment: еще в так старые цитаты вернуть, старую подсветку и старые очереди — и было бы старое доброе ruSO XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor  так: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5381/191482 ?

Answer (score 6):

Истина — выбор шрифта и его оформление является таким же важным элементом, как и выбор дизайна для сайта. Наблюдая последние изменения, не остается сомнений, что руководство SO заботится об этом.

Однако, стоит учитывать тот факт, что Stack Overflow — это площадка, куда пользователь приходит работать. Многие участники проводят здесь ежедневно по несколько часов в день. И главное для этого ресурса не внешний вид и красивые шрифты, а удобство и простота его использования. Текст на сайте должен быть читабельным (удобочитаемым) с визуальной точки зрения. SO — это текстовый информационный ресурс, содержащий преимущественно текстовую информацию. Поэтому выбранный шрифт является главной частью общего его визуального восприятия.

Скорость и простота восприятия текстовой информации в электронном формате во многом зависит от используемого шрифта. Шрифт должен быть легким и комфортным для прочтения, простым и удобным для восприятия, без излишней вычурности и импозантности. Он должен гармонировать на странице, поддерживая определенный контраст. На мой взгляд, предпочтительнее всего использовать шрифты из стандартного набора, такие, как например, Arial, Times New Roman, Verdana.

Возможно, для кого-то, у кого глазки еще совсем молодые, новые изменения зашли на радость. А вот на мой взгляд, особенно на главной странице, было лучше, стало хуже. Шрифт поменялся и стал меньше размером, от этого текст читать стало немного сложнее. Заголовки вопросов сливаются с тегами от того, что всё в голубом цвете.

*С пожеланиями RuSO, чтобы на главной напротив голубых строк почаще мелькали зеленые квадратики, Sevastopol'*

Comment: Что такое «стандартный набор»? Как быть линуксоидам, у которых нет ни одного из упомянутых шрифтов?

Comment: @andreymal, однозначно понимать это не нужно. Это как пример. Есть великое множество шрифтов, идентичных упомянутым.

Answer (score 5):

Не являюсь специалистом по шрифтам, но как "очкарик" могу сказать, что сайт читать стало гораздо хуже, глаза стали уставать заметно больше.

Каких-то скриптов ставить не планирую, рассчитываю, что вскоре поменяют обратно или подкорректируют шрифты. Ну а пока — буду сокращать время пребывания на сайте, глаза дороже.

Comment: Почитай [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021), там уже решений, как "откатить" под все браузеры выложено. Я "откатил" уже.

Answer (score 4):

Ко всему, конечно, можно привыкнуть. Но по моим собственным ощущениям (пользователя Windows и FF) итоговый шрифт стал хуже того, что был.

Текущее представление шрифта у меня вызывает чувство какой-то несерьёзности описываемой им информации. Может быть сказывается несколько большая близость (опять таки, сугубо по моим ощущениям, т.к. я не являюсь специалистом по шрифтам) текущего шрифта со шрифтами семейства Comic Sans, название которых уже само по себе говорит о том, что в первую очередь должно быть весело, а не серьёзно.

Можно даже эмоджи клоуна  не добавлять, т.к. он подразумевается автоматически.

Comment: И старый Arial, и новый Segoe UI в равной мере являются родственными Comic Sans. А чем Segoe UI хуже? Попробовал посмотреть на них в сравнении (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgjE9.png), вроде как они довольно похожи.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я думаю, надо смотреть в контексте, а не пару слов сравнивать. Например, [здесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siwJ7.png). Тут изменилось всё же несколько больше, чем просто шрифт. Тем не менее, прежний вариант мне более симпатичен.

Answer (score 3):

Для всех обновление. Это шрифты поменяли и у нас и в английском филиале.